# Extract method key/parameters from string

Tags: java, regex

I want a logic (regexp probably) through which i can extract the method key and parameters, from the below type of statements.

```
RuleResult executeRule(RuleData, RuleProperties, Locale) { /* some key */ }
// result: executeRule(RuleData, RuleProperties, Locale)

RuleResult executeRule() { /* some key */ }
// result: executeRule()

executeRule(RuleData, RuleProperties, Locale) { /* some key */ }
// result: executeRule(RuleData, RuleProperties, Locale)

executeRule() { /* some key */ }
// result: executeRule()

static executeRule(RuleData, RuleProperties, Locale) { /* some key */ }
// result: executeRule(RuleData, RuleProperties, Locale)

static executeRule() { /* some key */ }
// result: executeRule()
```

I tried some simple String split with Braces and White space, but not able to arrive at the desired result. What should I do?

Comment: In which language do you need this?

Comment: In java programming language..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `replaceAll()` with the appropriate parameters on your input:

```
input.replaceAll(".*(?<=^|\\s)(\\w+\\(.*?\\)).*", "$1");
```

This regex matches what you want to keep (using a "look behind") in group 1, but matches the whole input and replaces it with the group 1, thereby *keeping*, rather than *replacing*, what you want to keep.

Here's some test code with all of your samples:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] examples = { 
            "RuleResult executeRule(RuleData, RuleProperties, Locale) { /* some key */ }", 
            "RuleResult executeRule() { /* some key */ }",
            "executeRule(RuleData, RuleProperties, Locale) { /* some key */ }", 
            "executeRule() { /* some key */ }",
            "static executeRule(RuleData, RuleProperties, Locale) { /* some key */ }", 
            "static executeRule() { /* some key */ }" };
    for (String example : examples) {
        System.out.println(example + "\n// result: " + 
            example.replaceAll(".*(?<=^|\\s)(\\w+\\(.*?\\)).*", "$1") + "\n");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
RuleResult executeRule(RuleData, RuleProperties, Locale) { /* some key */ }
// result: executeRule(RuleData, RuleProperties, Locale)

RuleResult executeRule() { /* some key */ }
// result: executeRule()

executeRule(RuleData, RuleProperties, Locale) { /* some key */ }
// result: executeRule(RuleData, RuleProperties, Locale)

executeRule() { /* some key */ }
// result: executeRule()

static executeRule(RuleData, RuleProperties, Locale) { /* some key */ }
// result: executeRule(RuleData, RuleProperties, Locale)

static executeRule() { /* some key */ }
// result: executeRule()
```

Looks a lot like your sample data :)

Comment: Hi Bohemian, since it was urgency, i anyway did the same with some split, replace and regexp. But i think your solution is much more simple and elegant. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like you want to *match* something, not *split* it.

```
\w+\([^()]*\)
```

would match the required string in all your example cases.

**Explanation:**

```
\w+    # Match an alphanumeric "word"
\(     # Match an opening paren
[^()]* # Match any number of characters except parens
\)     # Match a closing paren
```

In Java:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\w+\\([^()]*\\)");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
    ResultString = regexMatcher.group();
}
```